# How to apply the Flutter Semantics widgets

Tags: flutter, accessibility

I'm just getting started with Flutter, and am trying to learn how to use the Accessibility Widgets provided as I work in the accessibility field. However, I am having a hard time finding any examples of how the semantics widgets are used.

I've read the API docs and other explanations of why semantics are used and the theory of what they do, but would really benefit from a concrete example of how they are used in an actual project.

For example, I was going through a tutorial on creating a startup name generator, which creates a list of names that can be Favorited and stored in a list on a second page of the application. [The main file link](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/startup_namer/step7_navigate_route/lib/main.dart)

When run, and tested with assistive technologies, Talkback screen reader, in my case, the button that takes you to the list of favorites announces as unlabeled. The heart icons also don't indicate their presents or current state. I would like to use the Semantics widget to give the first an alternative text label for accessibility and add text to the label of the list tiles to indicate favorite status.